# Ubuntu doesn't work - wubildr issue (and can I make my pc bootable without smartbootmanager which doesn't work)

Tags: wubi

I just installed ubuntu using the .exe installer. I tried 3 times before with a cd, but it didn't boot (whatever). When I turn on the laptop, and select ubuntu, I get an error or something (it disappears too fast for me to read it, I just noticed a word "error" in it).
Then the screen becomes black and nothing happens. Then I shut down the laptop using the power button. Please help I want to have ubuntu on my laptop WITHOUT uninstalling windows or reformatting.

Edit: I tried reinstalling and I got error again. This time I noticed more things:
non-ms, skip
error prefix
Did HP blocked ubuntu or something?

Some more info: I only ran wubi.exe and changed install size to 20gb and clicked install or whatever the button was. It finished in some time then it wanted to restart the computer. I clicked restart now. And when the computer turned off, it turned back on and I got that error again. So reinstalling didn't help. I think HP blocked it (I have HP Pavilion g7 1303). I'm not sure but I think "non-ms, skip" was a part of that error. (first line)

EDIT: I THINK I GOT THE WHOLE ERROR

```
non-ms; skip
no wubildr
error; prefix
```

AND CAN I MAKE MY HP PAVILION G7 1303 bootable and how?

Comment: Wubi is pretty unstable and choosing whether to install with or without Wubi is more a matter of preference than anything. However, if Wubi is giving you problems, just try installing using CD and repartioning.

Comment: I tried CD, but I it wasn't bootable for some reasons. Maybe I have non bootable cd drive or something

Comment: What do you mean "it was not bootable"? Did you just go straight to windows? Bonus question: what computer do you have?

Comment: It wasnt bootable: I always get empty black screen when I start the PC (maybe instead of that BIOS stuff) but when the CD was inserted I was waiting for something to happen, and then Windows ran

Comment: And I have hp pavilion g7 1303

Comment: What is that wubildr? I wanna know because the error contains:
"no wubildr"

Comment: My understanding is that your computer boots from the hard disk without polling other devices first. You might wish to enter BIOS and set the first boot device to your CD drive. Then you will be able to boot from the Ubuntu CD and install Ubuntu.

Comment: (continued) You might also wish to do some more reading before installing Ubuntu. It would be helpful to have a look at these installation instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD

Comment: "Empty black screen" - that's what you are looking for... identify your graphics card, search on that and try the `nomodeset` option: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 (all the other stuff are irrelevant artifacts of using wubi)

Comment: Another thing - you don't need (and shouldn't) hard poweroff a linux OS. There is a safe alternative you should familiarize yourself with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with installing Ubuntu. Using a CD - I let the Ubuntu environment run from the CD. Once it was running I used the desktop GUI Install icon. When it got to the partitioning part I asked to partition manually. Make sure that there is an .../sda partition for grub. Also insure that you have an .../sd1 partition of at least 10GB and a .../swap partition of 1GB or more. After completing the partitioning I let the install run to completion. It ejected the CD and I allowed it to restart. At this point Ubuntu became useable.

If the system is already a multiboot system this may not work because the loader is a Windows boot.ini based loader.

Comment: so I can't have ubuntu on my PC without reformatting? or removing windows?

Comment: You don't need to remove Windows. You can have Ubuntu installed alongside Windows. You just need enough space on your hard drive for two operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Wubi megathread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639198) at Ubuntu Forums. This will answer your question about what wubildr is as well as helps you on many related troubleshooting. Another good source is the [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) in the Ubuntu Wiki.

Comment: I readed this stuff before, but I don't understand anything except that I need to use terminal which is in ubuntu which DOESN'T BOOT

Comment: @MatejKranjec those were the cases when Ubuntu threw the error, "stalled" for a relatively short time (a minute? how long did you wait it out?), and then continued to boot nevertheless. But to make things easier for you, you could try with a "virtual machine" such as [Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) which is available for free: Install VirtualBox, and then install Ubuntu inside a virtual machine. If you later change your mind about re-partitioning, you can still go ahead, boot from the LiveCD, and let it install Ubuntu alongside your Windows.

Comment: I can't boot from CD

Comment: That's not necessary for a VirtualBox install. But as your question is about Wubi, that may be a different topic.

Comment: I tried virtualbox but when I try to install ubuntu on virtual machine, it says something like: This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.

Comment: download the 32bit image -- you've got the 64bit one. Point your browser to the [Download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), look at the right-hand side of it, make sure the selection says "32 bit (recommended)", which is the default, and press the "Start Download" button below it.

Comment: Does that mean that I can't have x64 ubuntu on my laptop (not virtual device)? and is it possible to make my pc bootable?

Comment: I cannot tell that. But you cannot have amd64 Ubuntu in your VirtualBox obviously. To check whether your laptop supports 64bit, see [hardware - How to find out if my system is i386 or x86_64 before installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103137/how-to-find-out-if-my-system-is-i386-or-x86-64-before-installing-ubuntu).

Comment: It doesn't say anything about **PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER**, but processor architecture would be useful, I already knew it. 
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6

Comment: What should I do now? Virtual device works! Is making my laptop bootable possible? If yes, please tell me how. My laptop skips that BIOS stuff when it starts. It only says press esc for menu or something

Comment: So that should answer the question: Yes, you can install either 32bit or 64bit to your convenience, your machine (not the VM) should accept it. You could simply create a 64bit CD or Stick and try out.

Comment: but... I tried that and finded out that my pc isn't bootable so when I put the cd in, turn the PC on and turn it on again, windows start and that's it.

Comment: @MatejKranjec long discussions are not much favored here, and we are already way off your original question, so this should be moved to at least a new one. Short answer to your last comment: You must go to your PCs BIOS, and set your CD/DVD drive as first boot drive (you can revert that later). The PC always starts from the first bootable medium it can find, so if there's no DVD in the drive, it will go check the HDD as well -- but if HDD comes first, it never checks the DVD.

Comment: I cant open that bios stuff it says I must press esc to run BIOS and stuff and then I click esc and nuthin' happen. Then I hold esc and nothing happens